# Strange Silverlight/Ria Services SP2 Issue

Tags: silverlight, ria

I am experiencing a strange error while running Silverlight 5 and Ria Services SP2. I receive the 'highly informative' Not Found error when running my application, and the trace log shows the following exception:

The incoming HTTP request's URI 'http://localhost:57502/Services/CompanyName-Data-Web-Services-DBService.svc/binary/binary/GetTblA' does not match any service operation.

followed next by this exception:

The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the message is not supported by the encoder.

I am not sure why the URL contains two /binary/binary (is it supposed to be this way, or is THAT the issue?), but I have not been able to find records of anyone else having this problem. I am thinking more and more that it may be a bug with Ria SP2.

The exception is thrown (what seems to be) randomly. Sometimes it will work, other times it will throw this exception. I have not been able to find a pattern as to when it crashes and when it works.

Can anyone help me? This is incredibly frustrating!

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Comment: Well it should only contain one binary, are you using any custom query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you have ALL references of client and server projects updated to SL5 and RIA SP2 and EDM4.1
There may be some entires which have "Use specific version" pointing to older assemblies.